# Drawing rectangles

Tags: texturing

How can I draw any shape rectangle in Blender on the mesh?

For example, like in GIMP.

[image]

Comment: If you mean how to _decorate_ a mesh surface with rectangles, you should deepen your knowledge about _texturing_ models, UV texturing in particular. Be more specific about your mesh, and show how it looks.

Comment: If you mean how to create rectangles in the UV/Image Editor, I don't think you can, you need to use Photoshop or this kind of soft, but you can create straight line though: in the UV/Image Editor window, press E and choose Line, if you drag your cursor you can see that you draw lines, if you press alt they will be horizontal or vertical

Comment: As far as I know, you can draw lines (and freehand curves) not rectangles on a mesh. Here's tutorial on hand painting a mesh: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcCQKuWPhXk

Comment: @m.ardito it's a simple sphere but I would like to texture it with various shapes of rectangles

Comment: @moonboots I don't have photoshop

Comment: @BlenderDadaist Thanks. I used this tutorial for texturing. This tutorial shows hand painting. I used this as a base and on top of it I would like to creates rectangle shapes.

Comment: you can't do everything you want with Blender, it's a 3D software, not 2D, there are free 2D softs like Gimp or Krita, you should check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a rectangle in place of an empty on some object by computing its shape using the texture coordinates of that empty in the object's shader:

[image: Node Tree]

To add another rectangle, add another empty, create another node tree for it and mix the results.

Answer (score 0):

This could not be ideal for you, but you could use blender mesh modeling to draw... rectangles, assign shadeless materials to them, stack them on a white background (world), use an orthographic camera oriented Z down, and, then, simply render the image. Like this:

[image]

Save the rendered image to disk and use it as any other texture to decorate your objects. Like this:

[image]

Of course you're not limited to rectangles, in this way you can use blender modeling tools to draw anything, pictures, videos, and also import svg vector files, convert them to meshes, and more...

Comment: Omar Ahmad,  @m.ardito thank you. Both answers very helpful.